# How to Group each month in a year

Tags: sql, oracle

this my oracle query..   am tried in many but it showing different errors
my condition is to show 12 month if no data display 0 value if data just show value .....

```
select distinct 
COUNTRY_NAME,                       
TRAN_DATE,
ROUND (nvl(sum(WALKIN_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0)/ COUNT(*),2)APC,
ROUND((nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE),0)+nvl(sum(total_sales),0)-nvl(sum(net_sales),0)+nvl(sum(discount),0))/nvl(sum(BILLS_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0))ASPB,
ROUND((nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE),0)+nvl(sum(total_sales),0)-nvl(sum(net_sales),0)+nvl(sum(discount),0))/COUNT(*),2) ASPD,
nvl(sum(BILLS_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0) Bill,
trunc(nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE),0)+nvl(sum(total_sales),0)-nvl(sum(net_sales),0)+nvl(sum(discount),0)) Sale,
nvl(sum(WALKIN_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0) WALKINS
from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B
WHERE  A.OUTLET_ID=B.OUTLET_ID and SALES_VALUE>0
and rownum <=300
group by COUNTRY_NAME,                      
TRAN_DATE
```

And the Desired Output should be like this:

```
MONTH          APC             sale
----- -------           

    01          0      0
    02          0      0
    03          0      0
    04          0      12    
    05          0      14
    06          1       0
    07          1       0
    08          0       0
    09          0       0
    10          2       0
    11          1       0
    12          0       0
```

Comment: From what source data that desired output should be like that? Please provide an example.

Comment: You are getting that `ORA-00923:` error because in your in-line view comma is missing between literal `'01'` and `to_char(tran_date,'mm')` -> `select '01', to_char(tran_date,'mm')...`

Comment: is joining correct in ma query?

Comment: again i have tried but its showing error like java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a comma in between the columns in your select statement

```
    select '01', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '02', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '03', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '04', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '05', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '06', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '07', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '08', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '09', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '10', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '11', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B union all
select '12', to_char(tran_date,'mm') from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT
```

Comment: i am not sure, for the error you specified the cause is this comma, try it and let us know if there is any further issue, so that i will evaluate it further @Exeptional

Comment: i have edited which i have tried but again its showing a error like java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: I also believe this two statement are causing the issue, i am not sure,     and tran_date >= DATE'2012-01-01' 
   And tran_date < DATE'2013-12-01'   try removing the date after the relational operators....

Comment: i have edited post ..this my original query its working fine but my need is to show 12 month by union ......

Comment: I am sorry @Exeptional i am not able to work further on this... Please check with others.......

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, 8 out of 10 cases of

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

error is due to a missing comma